# How to change Run window view to just the output in IntelliJ in a Gradle-based project

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image]

It currently looks like this, which is very similar to the Debug window's console, and which I do not like.

Before it used to show something along the lines of

```
*java kotlinc stuff like that commands here(It was condensed so I'm not sure on the exact details)*

Part 1: 232
Part 2: 1783
```

Now it shows the above screenshot.

I'm not sure what caused this issue, I was having a few issues with the Kotlin plugin, I proceeded to reinstall and restart IntelliJ it which fixed the issues I was having but it changed the view to this.

I'm running on version 2020.3.1 of IntelliJ Ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Gradle-based projects, IDE by default delegates the build and run actions to Gradle.

If you want to run and build with IDE's own runner and builder, switch to **IntelliJ IDEA** the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | **Build and run using**.

See also [Configure the build and run actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-gradle-projects.html#delegate_build_gradle) documentation about this functionality.